# TeX Stack Exchange swag for top users

Tags: discussion

As a thank you for *being awesome*, if you have at least 950 reputation and are on page 1 or page 2 of …

https://tex.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

… we'll be sending you a little care package shortly:

- TeX Stack Exchange t-shirt in your size
- TeX Stack Exchange die-cut, vinyl stickers
- [Stack Exchange sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies)
- [Stack Exchange pen](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens)
- [Stack Exchange stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers)

You can expect to get an email soon with details on how to confirm and provide your mailing address and size preferences.

### The t-shirt

[image: tex.stackexchange.com Tshirt]

### The sticker

[image: tex.stackexchange.com sticker]

The rest of the items you can view in the [Stack Exchange store](http://shop.stackexchange.com) — direct links to [sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies), [pens](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens), [stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers).

Congratulations!

<sub>(for anyone else who wants this swag, but isn't on page 1 or page 2 of the all time top users -- the limited edition t-shirts and stickers will be available for purchase from the store soon as well)</sub>

Comment: all credit to [Andrew Stacey](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/86/andrew-stacey) for the nice geometric shape used in the t-shirt design. He gave us permission to use it!

Comment: A million thanks! It's just a pity that the [beer stein](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/beer-stein) is not part of the package ;-) Here in Bavaria I would use it more often than the pen :-D

Comment: Thank you very much! These are pretty cool.

Comment: Schweet!  Another SE sticker for the office, and a t-shirt to run in.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Damn, only page 3 ;) Will the t-shirts be available in other colors then white (black/navy/olive/anthracite) ?

Comment: Thank you! This will be the envy of all my friends who use MSWord, and a few who use the IBM Magnetic Tape/Selectric Typewriter.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: "Here in Bavaria" but "location Limerick, Ireland" (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975/martin-scharrer)? Got me confused.

Comment: @Stephen: I moved recently back to Germany, but lived in Ireland for some years.

Comment: I got my package today. Thank you StackExchange! :)

Comment: Good to know, so now it's time to really start waiting for it. You're still in Chicago? I guess it'll be a bit longer to Europe.

Comment: arrived yesterday.  very nice logo -- thank you very much!

Comment: @doncherry: Yes. I actually got the delivery notification on Friday (but wasn't at home) and couldn't figure out what package I was supposed to get. Was a nice surprise when I got the package yesterday.

Comment: Mine arrived today, thank you so much :)

Comment: @doncherry: Not too long — I received the post notification today!

Comment: I wrote something with my pen today. Unfortunately, my handwriting is terrible, so it didn't look as good as what I write in TeX.

Comment: Got mine today. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: Sweeeet, arrived today. A million thanks! `:-D` I feel so proud, I think I should renew my gravatar wearing the shirt `:-D`

Comment: For a reason that I don't want to share here and if I am eligible for the package, I will present it to [Peteris Krumins](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5177/peteris-krumins). Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand why my answer was converted to a comment while Caramdir's answer here is not converted to a comment. The essence of comments from other members to Jeff Atwood's "question" is almost the same as the content of this "answer"-- just saying the package has arrived and thank you. To be fair, Caramdir's "answer" should be converted to a comment as well, what do you think guys? :-)

Comment: Response to doncherry's comment in my "answer" that has been converted to a comment above: The real reason is I have no permanent address to claim the package. I want to see Peteris Krumins wearing the t-shirt on his blog. :-) Thank you!

Comment: The link to the Stack Exchange store is broken now! :-(

Comment: @paul yes, unfortunately the store was discontinued, per http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store

Comment: @JeffAtwood Thank for the link: you can maybe add a little note about it in the article above... Can we expect a new sale (even if it only lasts a few days)? This t-shirt looks really cool!

Answer (score 17):

Here you can see the swag package. I made the photo during the TeX Users Group Conference 2011 in India, where it's been arranged on a table in a room where we met for coffee breaks during the conference.

[image: swag table TUG 2011]

Comment: Ah, nice! I can't wait until I get my package.